# How do I access my ignite cache using pyignite

Tags: python, ignite

I am running an Ignite++ node using the following cache configuration

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="CACHE_SCHEMA"/>

            ....

            <property name="queryEntities">
              <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                  <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                  <property name="valueType" value="CACHE_NAME"/>

                  <property name="fields">
                    <map>
                      <entry key="Ref" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                    </map>
                  </property>
                </bean>
              </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Using Ignite++ I can put & get data to this cache just fine (I very much follow the put_and_get example that comes with ignite). However, I can't see to do the same using pyignite.

```
>>> from pyignite import Client
>>> igniteClient = Client()
>>> igniteClient.connect('10.1.8.166', 10800)
>>> igniteClient.get_cache_names()
['CACHE_SCHEMA']
```

How do I Put & Get into CACHE_NAME when that isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the cache is named `CACHE_SCHEMA`.

It's the value type, and table name, that are called `CACHE_NAME`.

So for put-get you need to use former, for any SQL including `INSERT`'s, the latter.

Comment: No, for SQL (including INSERT) I use CACHE_SCHEMA.CACHE_NAME. For put-get in C++ I create a cache object using CACHE_SCHEMA. And then a binary object where I return CACHE_NAME in the GetTypeName() handle. I am just looking for the equivalent of that in python.

Comment: `igniteClient.get_cache('CACHE_SCHEMA')`?